# Excel VBA AutoFit based on a certain range?

Tags: vba, excel

I can use `Range("A3:D9").EntireColumn.AutoFit` to fix column widths based on the widest column in each column `A:D`

However, `Range("A3:D9").AutoFit` doesn't work - I think I understand why, AutoFit is a method applicable to EntireColumn only! - I think?!

Is there a way to get this to work - to use the AutoFit to fix column widths based on **the max col width in each column in my range** and *not* the entire column?

Comment: Have you tried doing it manually?  Testing for the longest string in those cells, then adjusting column width based on that?

Comment: You could loop through each cell to find the max length or use a formula? Or copy the relevant cells to another sheet, autofit there and find the resulting width.

Comment: Try `Range("A3:D9").Columns.AutoFit`

Comment: So you want columns A:D to all be the same width as each other and the width is dependent upon the largest column width among columns A:D?

Comment: Interesting ideas from everyone, but I tried @BrakNicku's and it worked perfectly. Please put this as an answer so I can accept it! - and not eaxctly Scott - not the same width as each other, each column as wide as the max width in the column's range instead of the entirecolumn

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From [AutoFit manual](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/range-columns-property-excel):

> The **Range** object must be a row or a range of rows, or a column or a range of columns. Otherwise, this method generates an error.

So the solution to autofit columns/rows only for specific area is to use:

```
Range("A3:D9").Columns.AutoFit
Range("A3:D9").Rows.AutoFit
```

This code:

```
Range("A3:D9").AutoFit
```

Does not specify whether columns or rows should be adjusted. It could probably adjust both, but the designers of the language decided to throw an error instead.

Comment: Great solution, perfect answer, well-described